# I want to use emmet-mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs24, emmet

I want to use emmet-mode in emacs with .jade files but emmet-mode don't work. It expand html but not jade sintaxis.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to use a different _syntax_, or simply to use `emmet-mode`'s features in files that end with `.jade`?

Comment: Yeah, only files with .jade

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [the Optional Settings section of the `README.md`](https://github.com/smihica/emmet-mode#3-optional-settings), you can enable `emmet-mode` based on major mode like so:

```
(add-hook 'jade-mode-hook #'emmet-mode)
```

`emmet-mode` should now be enabled with `jade-mode`, and `C-j` should be bound to `emmet-expand-line`.